# Trying to use dplyr to group_by and apply scale()

Tags: r, dplyr

Trying to use `dplyr` to `group_by` the `stud_ID` variable in the following data frame, as in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26950045/group-by-and-scale-normalize-a-column-in-r):

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   4136 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ stud_ID         : chr  "ABB112292" "ABB112292" "ABB112292" "ABB112292" ...
 $ behavioral_scale: num  3.5 4 3.5 3 3.5 2 NA NA 1 2 ...
 $ cognitive_scale : num  3.5 3 3 3 3.5 2 NA NA 1 1 ...
 $ affective_scale : num  2.5 3.5 3 3 2.5 2 NA NA 1 1.5 ...
```

I tried the following to obtain scale scores by student (rather than scale scores for observations across all students):

```
scaled_data <- 
          df %>%
              group_by(stud_ID) %>%
                  mutate(behavioral_scale_ind = scale(behavioral_scale),
                         cognitive_scale_ind = scale(cognitive_scale),
                         affective_scale_ind = scale(affective_scale))
```

Here is the result:

```
> str(scaled_data)
Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 4136 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ stud_ID             : chr  "ABB112292" "ABB112292" "ABB112292" "ABB112292" ...
 $ behavioral_scale    : num  3.5 4 3.5 3 3.5 2 NA NA 1 2 ...
 $ cognitive_scale     : num  3.5 3 3 3 3.5 2 NA NA 1 1 ...
 $ affective_scale     : num  2.5 3.5 3 3 2.5 2 NA NA 1 1.5 ...
 $ behavioral_scale_ind: num [1:12, 1] 0.64 1.174 0.64 0.107 0.64 ...
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= num 2.9
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= num 0.937
 $ cognitive_scale_ind : num [1:12, 1] 1.17 0.64 0.64 0.64 1.17 ...
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= num 2.4
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= num 0.937
 $ affective_scale_ind : num [1:12, 1] 0 1.28 0.64 0.64 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= num 2.5
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= num 0.782
```

The three scaled variables (`behavioral_scale`, `cognitive_scale`, and `affective_scale`) have only 12 observations - the same number of observations for the first student, `ABB112292`.

What's going on here? How can I obtain scaled scores by individual?

Comment: Have you looked into `summarise()` in `dplyr` ?

Comment: I think you should mutate before you group, or you are going to center every student's score on him/herself

Comment: @C8H10N4O2, on him/herself, so each student's observations will have M = 0 and SD = 1

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the base `scale()` function, which expects a matrix.  Try writing your own.

```
scale_this <- function(x){
  (x - mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)) / sd(x, na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

Then this works:

```
library("dplyr")

# reproducible sample data
set.seed(123)
n = 1000
df <- data.frame(stud_ID = sample(LETTERS, size=n, replace=TRUE),
                 behavioral_scale = runif(n, 0, 10),
                 cognitive_scale = runif(n, 1, 20),
                 affective_scale = runif(n, 0, 1) )
scaled_data <- 
  df %>%
  group_by(stud_ID) %>%
  mutate(behavioral_scale_ind = scale_this(behavioral_scale),
         cognitive_scale_ind = scale_this(cognitive_scale),
         affective_scale_ind = scale_this(affective_scale))
```

Or, if you're open to a `data.table` solution:

```
library("data.table")

setDT(df)

cols_to_scale <- c("behavioral_scale","cognitive_scale","affective_scale")

df[, lapply(.SD, scale_this), .SDcols = cols_to_scale, keyby = factor(stud_ID)]
```

Answer (score 18):

This was a [known problem](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1918) in dplyr, a fix has been merged to the development version, which you can install via

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")
```

In the stable version, the following should work, too:

```
scale_this <- function(x) as.vector(scale(x))
```

Comment: Hi krlmlr, given the age of this answer, would it be fair to say that this behaviour has been reverted in a subsequent version change?

Comment: Yes, I should have added a version number to the answer back then. These days, in dplyr >= 1.0.2, matrices can be used without problems in columns, so I suspect the original problem no longer occurs?

Comment: Ah nevermind. It works, but the column names then show up with `[,1]` which can be a little confusing.

Comment: The column1[,1] does not vanish even after piping `set_colnames`

Comment: To remove [,1], it seems you can either: `df%>% mutate(scaled=as.vector(scale(value))` or `df %>% mutate(scaled=scale(value)[,1])`

Answer (score 10):

```
df <- df %>% mutate(across(is.numeric, ~ as.numeric(scale(.))))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: @novonimo's point is always important, but it's _especially_ important here where there's already a well-established accepted answer that's been validated by the community with nearly 40 upvotes. Under what circumstances is your approach preferable over the accepted answer? Are you taking advantage of new capabilities or syntax?

Comment: A simple and elegant solution! In my opinion, the best of all of the above. Brawo @SparklingWater!