# Scale values in a dataframe by category

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a data frame as follows:

```
d <- data.frame(
    shop=c('A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','D','E','E'),
    product=c(1:5,1:3,1:4,1,1:2), 
    price=c(16.83, 12.21, 9.99, 3.99, 1.00,
      19.50, 6.42, 1.89,
      13.95, 12.50, 7.87, 0.79,
      11.99,
      22.80, 15.99)  )
```

The data represent the prices of products held by shops, with the products  numbered in reverse price-order within each shop. I'd like to discover various things (e.g., mean, distribution, maximum price) about the most expensive products *across stores*, and similarly about the least expensive. With that in mind, I want to rescale the product numbering so that in all stores, the most expensive is numbered 1 and the least expensive is numbered 10 (with fractional product numbers being just fine).

Things I know:

1. How to scale a single vector of product numbers using the maximum
   and minimum values
2. How to obtain the maximum product number by shop:
   `aggregate(d[, 2], list(d$shop), max)`

But I don't see how to fit the pieces together so that, for example, the product numbers for shop `C` are, from most expensive to least expensive, `c(1,4,7,10)`.

Comment: Please show how you arrived at `c(1,4,7,10)` for C and how you define the scale for #1.

Comment: As I say in the OP, I am not trying to rescale the prices --- as shown in the answer below from misuse. I'm trying to rescale the product numbers. Rescaling four numbers, 1:4, over the range 1:10 gives an equal gap of 3 between the numbers ... c(1, 4, 7, 10). Of course, it is easy to make the slight change needed to @misuse answer.

Comment: It looks as if my question is a duplicate. I hadn't realised. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761018/scale-all-values-depending-on-group

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using `dplyr` and `scales::rescale`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(shop) %>% #group by shop
    arrange(shop, desc(price)) %>% #arrange by shop and price
    mutate(scaled = 1:n(), #create a label for price (in this case it matches the product id but in some cases it might not)
           scaled = scales::rescale(scaled, to = c(1, 10)))
```

scale to range 1 - 10

```
#output
# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups:   shop [5]
   shop  product price scaled
   <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 A           1 16.8    1   
 2 A           2 12.2    3.25
 3 A           3  9.99   5.5 
 4 A           4  3.99   7.75
 5 A           5  1     10   
 6 B           1 19.5    1   
 7 B           2  6.42   5.5 
 8 B           3  1.89  10   
 9 C           1 14.0    1   
10 C           2 12.5    4   
11 C           3  7.87   7   
12 C           4  0.79  10   
13 D           1 12.0    5.5 #one item in category, it is both min and max, so (1+10)/2 = 5.5
14 E           1 22.8    1   
15 E           2 16.0   10
```

to get max product number one can use summarise after grouping:

```
df %>%
  group_by(shop) %>%
  summarise(max = max(product))
#output
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  shop    max
  <fct> <dbl>
1 A      5.00
2 B      3.00
3 C      4.00
4 D      1.00
5 E      2.00
```

or if one wants to summarise several variables at once (here on columns 2 and 3):

```
df %>%
  group_by(shop) %>%
  summarise_at(2:3, max)
## A tibble: 5 x 3
  shop  product price
  <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 A        5.00  16.8
2 B        3.00  19.5
3 C        4.00  14.0
4 D        1.00  12.0
5 E        2.00  22.8
```

Comment: Thanks ... but note also that it is the product numbers, not the prices that I want to rescale; it's only a tiny change from the solution you've shown. By rescaling the prices, one ends up with all "most expensive" products valued at 1, whereas I want to retain the actual price so I can determine the distribution of all "least expensive" products (for example).