# scale values within group in R

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3),y=c(1,3,4,3,5,2,3))
```

I'd to create a column with the scaled values of `y` for each element of `x`
so when `x==1` --> `scale(c(1,3))`, `x==2` --> `scale(4,3)`, etc

This is what I'm trying to achieve

```
x  y  y2
1  1  -0.7071
1  3   0.7071
2  4   0.7071
2  3  -0.7071
3  5  -0.2182
3  2   1.0910
3  3  -0.8728
```

Comment: what about ex for x ==3??

Comment: @Neel: scale(c(5,2,3)) = -0.2182, 1.0910, -0.8728

Comment: Try to use ```dplyr``` package to group by ```x```. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775696/trying-to-use-dplyr-to-group-by-and-apply-scale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could apply `scale` function by group :

This can be done in base R:

```
df$y2 <- with(df, ave(y, x, FUN = scale))
df

#  x y        y2
#1 1 1 -0.707107
#2 1 3  0.707107
#3 2 4  0.707107
#4 2 3 -0.707107
#5 3 5  1.091089
#6 3 2 -0.872872
#7 3 3 -0.218218
```

`dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(y2 = scale(y))
```

and in `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, y2 := scale(y), x]
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3),y=c(1,3,4,3,5,2,3))
```

Comment: dplyr method is incorrect.

Comment: @Neel I get same output in all the 3 methods. If you are using OP's data then note that OP has 6 rows in their data whereas in expected output they have shown 7 rows. Updated the post with data I have used.

Comment: damn true and that's y when I used OP's data, the results were not matching.