# Data wrangling in Shiny: plotting newly wrangled data after k-means clustering analysis

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, k-means, data-wrangling

I am trying to build a data analytics dashboard and I am using Shiny, which I am relatively new to. One of the features of my dashboard uses k-means clustering on user generated data. I can get the clustering analysis to work fine, but I want to be able to exploratory data analysis on individual clusters once the initial cluster analysis has been done. Also, I would like to do this with reactive data frames in Shiny, so that if the user changes a value on the dash board, the analysis refreshes, including the post-clustering exploratory stuff.

Before anything, here are some functions that I use in the dashboard server code and relevant libraries, so run these first:-

```
#libraries===================================================================
library(ids)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(factoextra)

#functions required==========================================================
#scale https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775696/trying-to-use-dplyr-to-group-by-and-apply-scale
scale_this <- function(x){
  (x - mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)) / sd(x, na.rm=TRUE)
}


#wss plot 

wssplot <- function(data, nc = 15, seed = 1234) {
  wss <- (nrow(data) - 1) * sum(apply(data, 2, var))
  for (i in 2:nc) {
    set.seed(seed)
    wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(data, centers = i)$withinss)
  }
  plot(1:nc,
       wss,
       type = "b",
       xlab = "Number of Clusters",
       ylab = "Within groups sum of squares")
}
```

Here is the code for the mock data frame for this example:-

```
#Create my mock data frame============================================
set.seed(123)
randomid<-random_id(333)#from 'ids' library
Duration<-c(floor(runif(10000, min=1, max=1000)))
mockdf<-cbind(randomid, Duration)
mockdf<-as.data.frame(mockdf)
mockdf$Duration<-as.numeric(mockdf$Duration)
```

My UI code:-

```
#UI============================================================================

ui<-fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Minimal example'),
  tabsetPanel(
    
    
    #=============================================kmeans clustering==================================================
    
    
    tabPanel("User Type Discovery",
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(width = 4,numericInput('ksolution', 'Select k solution', 5),
                            pickerInput('userselect', 'Which users do you want to include:', 
                                        choices = unique(mockdf$randomid), options = list('actions-box'=TRUE),multiple = T)),
               mainPanel(fluidRow(
                 column(12, plotOutput("elbowplot")),
                 column(12, plotOutput("clustplot")),
                 column(12, plotOutput("clust_dens")),
                 column(12, DT::dataTableOutput('Clusterdf'))))
             )
    )
  )
)
```

And my server code:-

```
#SERVER===========================================================
server<-function(input,output,session){

  
  
  
  #create reactive dataframe
  rval_df <-reactive({
    mockdf
  })
  
  
  
  #=============================================kmeans clustering==================================================
  
  
  
  rval_UserData<-reactive({
    
    rval_df()%>%
      filter(randomid %in% input$userselect)%>%
      group_by(randomid)%>%
      summarise(Count=n(),MeanDuration=mean(Duration),SDDuration=sd(Duration))%>%
      mutate(SDDuration=if_else(is.na(SDDuration),0,SDDuration),
      Cluster=as.factor(rval_kclust()$cluster))
    
  })
  
  
  #create a scaled dataset for the clustering
  rval_cluster_df<-reactive({
    
    
    rval_df()%>%    
      filter(randomid %in% input$userselect)%>%
      group_by(randomid)%>%
      summarise(Count=n(),MeanDuration=mean(Duration),SDDuration=sd(Duration))%>%
      mutate(SDDuration=if_else(is.na(SDDuration),0,SDDuration),
             Count=scale_this(Count),
             MeanDuration=scale_this(MeanDuration),
             SDDuration=scale_this(SDDuration))%>%
      select(Count,MeanDuration,SDDuration)
    
    
  })  
  
  
  
  #cluster algorithm
  rval_kclust<-reactive({
    kmeans(rval_cluster_df(), centers = input$ksolution)
  })
  
  
  
  
  output$clustplot<-renderPlot({
    
    
    
    
    factoextra::fviz_cluster(rval_kclust(), data = rval_cluster_df()) 
    
    
  })
  
  
  output$elbowplot<-renderPlot({
    
    wssplot(rval_cluster_df())
  })
  
  
  output$Clusterdf<- DT::renderDataTable({
    rval_UserData()
    
  })
  
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When you run `shinyApp(ui,server)`, hit the "Select All" button in the drop down box in the app to run the clustering.

Now, here is what I want to do. Since I have assigned the cluster number back onto `rval_UserData()`, I want to be able to merge this assign the cluster number to `mockdf`, so I can generate plots using `ggplot2` on the `Duration` variable and also generate summary tables, all at cluster level.  I prefer to be able to do this using reactive data frames, so the plots will up refresh depending on the `ksolution` input in the UI.

Here's some of my attempts to merge the cluster number back onto the `mockdf`, followed by an attempt to plot a density plot:-

```
  rval_cluster_merged_df<-reactive({
    
    merge(mockdf(), rval_UserData(), by="randomid")
  #outside of shiny, this would be a quick way to paste the cluster number back onto the mock dataframe
          
  })
  
  
  
  output$clust_dens<-renderPlot({
    
   dd<-rval_cluster_merged_df()
    
      ggplot(dd,aes(x=Duration, colour=Cluster, group=Cluster))+
      geom_density()+ggtitle("Cluster density plot")+scale_x_log10()
    
  })
```

And this is what I get, see the error message:-

[image: minimal_example]

It's probably something obvious that I am doing wrong but any pointers in the right direction would be well appreciated! Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `req()` for all the `input$abc` variables, and `eval_tidy` as they are not standard variables.  Minor update to your server function as shown below will solve your problem.

```
server<-function(input,output,session){
  
  #create reactive dataframe
  rval_df <-reactive({
    mockdf
  })
   
  #=============================================kmeans clustering==================================================
  rval_UserData<-reactive({
    req(input$userselect)
    userselect <- eval_tidy(input$userselect)
    rval_df()%>%
      filter(randomid %in% userselect)%>%
      group_by(randomid)%>%
      summarise(Count=n(),MeanDuration=mean(Duration),SDDuration=sd(Duration))%>%
      mutate(SDDuration=if_else(is.na(SDDuration),0,SDDuration),
             Cluster=as.factor(rval_kclust()$cluster))
    
  })
  
  #create a scaled dataset for the clustering
  rval_cluster_df<-reactive({
    req(input$userselect)
    userselect <- eval_tidy(input$userselect)
    rval_df()%>%    
      filter(randomid %in% userselect)%>%
      group_by(randomid)%>%
      summarise(Count=n(),MeanDuration=mean(Duration),SDDuration=sd(Duration))%>%
      mutate(SDDuration=if_else(is.na(SDDuration),0,SDDuration),
             Count=scale_this(Count),
             MeanDuration=scale_this(MeanDuration),
             SDDuration=scale_this(SDDuration))%>%
      select(Count,MeanDuration,SDDuration)
    
  }) 
  
  #cluster algorithm
  rval_kclust<-reactive({
    req(input$ksolution)
    centers <- as.numeric(eval_tidy(input$ksolution))
    kmeans(rval_cluster_df(), centers = centers)
  })
  
  output$clustplot<-renderPlot({
    
    factoextra::fviz_cluster(rval_kclust(), data = rval_cluster_df()) 
    
  })
  
  
  output$elbowplot<-renderPlot({
    
    wssplot(rval_cluster_df())
  })
  
  output$Clusterdf<- DT::renderDataTable({
    rval_UserData()
    
  })
  
  rval_cluster_merged_df<-reactive({
    
    merge(rval_df(), rval_UserData(), by="randomid")

  })

  output$clust_dens<-renderPlot({
    
    dd<-rval_cluster_merged_df()
    
    ggplot(dd,aes(x=Duration, colour=Cluster, group=Cluster))+
      geom_density()+ggtitle("Cluster density plot")+scale_x_log10()
    
  })
  
}
```

Final output will be:

[image: output]

Comment: Hi @YBS, thanks for the response.  How should I modify the code for the density plots (in the code section just prior to the image I uploaded). I had tried adding in the req() functions into the code but no joy. 
Apologies, it will take me a while to understand these new functions!

Comment: I see, you have the density plot code in a separate section of your OP.

Comment: Your density plots are in the updated server code answer.

Comment: @RobinTurkington, Generally it would be considered polite to accept the answer that has answered your query.

Comment: Hi @YBS. I have accepted your solution as I am only getting around to viewing it now :) Thank you for your help