# Grouping, Selecting, and Mutate using R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that contains quite a few variables. I want to group the variables I am examining by year, then standardize them. Here is an example DF:

```
DF:

Var1   Var2   Year  BioTest   MathExam   WritingScore   Var3  Var 4
 X      X     2016   165        140         10           X     X
 X      X     2017   172        128         11           X     X
 X      X     2018   169        115          8           X     X
 X      X     2016   166        139         10           X     X
 X      X     2017   165        140         12           X     X

etc
```

I have been trying these codes, but cannot seem to get it right:

```
DF<-DF %>%
group_by(Year) %>%
mutate(across(c("BioTest", "MathExam", "WritingScore")), scale)
```

and

```
DF<-DF %>%
group_by(Year) %>%
mutate(c(BioTest, MathExam, WritingScore)), scale)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest next approach with a `dplyr` example using `across()`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
data(iris)
#Code
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(across(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width,scale))
```

In `across()` I have defined the range of variables I want to scale, and the function.

The output:

```
# A tibble: 150 x 5
# Groups:   Species [3]
   Sepal.Length[,1] Sepal.Width[,1] Petal.Length[,1] Petal.Width[,1] Species
              <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl> <fct>  
 1           0.267           0.190            -0.357          -0.436 setosa 
 2          -0.301          -1.13             -0.357          -0.436 setosa 
 3          -0.868          -0.601            -0.933          -0.436 setosa 
 4          -1.15           -0.865             0.219          -0.436 setosa 
 5          -0.0170          0.454            -0.357          -0.436 setosa 
 6           1.12            1.25              1.37            1.46  setosa 
 7          -1.15           -0.0739           -0.357           0.512 setosa 
 8          -0.0170         -0.0739            0.219          -0.436 setosa 
 9          -1.72           -1.39             -0.357          -0.436 setosa 
10          -0.301          -0.865             0.219          -1.39  setosa 
# ... with 140 more rows
```

Original names are kept, as in your initial dataframe. In the case of your piece of data you added this is the code and result:

```
df %>% group_by(Year) %>% mutate(across(BioTest:WritingScore,scale))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   Year [3]
   Year BioTest[,1] MathExam[,1] WritingScore[,1]
  <int>       <dbl>        <dbl>            <dbl>
1  2016      -0.707        0.707          NaN    
2  2017       0.707       -0.707           -0.707
3  2018     NaN          NaN              NaN    
4  2016       0.707       -0.707          NaN    
5  2017      -0.707        0.707            0.707
```

You can further process the output, but with real data you should have more observations.

Some of used data for final part is:

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2016L, 2017L), BioTest = c(165L, 
172L, 169L, 166L, 165L), MathExam = c(140L, 128L, 115L, 139L, 
140L), WritingScore = c(10L, 11L, 8L, 10L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: I just tried this, and this is the error I get:

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Problem with `across()` input `.fns`.
i Input `.fns` must be NULL, a function, a formula, or a list of functions/formulas.
i Input `..1` is `across(...)`.
i The error occured in group 1: TestYear = 2008.

The columns I need are all not in a row, and I have entered them followed by a comma. I.E. ...across(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, scale)). Am I entering something wrong?

Comment: @JeffB In `across` you must include your variables.Try `across(c(var1,var2,varn),scale)` inside `mutate()` Let me know if that works!

Comment: Something like this `df %>% group_by(Year) %>% mutate(across(c(BioTest,WritingScore),scale))` @JeffB Also check the final part of the answer!

Comment: This worked! I do have some NAs in my data, do I need to write in "na.rm= TRUE" in this code? Thanks!

Comment: @JeffB Great it worked, for `NA` is better if you check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775696/trying-to-use-dplyr-to-group-by-and-apply-scale :)

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) scale(x)[,1]), Year]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2016L, 2017L), BioTest = c(165L, 
172L, 169L, 166L, 165L), MathExam = c(140L, 128L, 115L, 139L, 
140L), WritingScore = c(10L, 11L, 8L, 10L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```